# What is the format used to represent Date and time in the Goldmine CONTTLOG.LOGSTAMP field?

Tags: crm, goldmine

The two Goldmine tables CONTTLOG and GMTLOG were intended for the GoldSync functionality, however I will be able to use these tables to investigate and report which user made a change and when.

In order to know the when I need to know the format used to represent Date and time in the LOGSTAMP field.

Have asked same question here: https://forums.ivanti.com/s/question/0D54O00007Kfh7MSAR/what-is-the-format-used-to-represent-date-and-time-in-the-logstamp-field

Answer (score 0):

Question is answered in the forum as below, looks like I may want to modernise the SQL:

https://forums.ivanti.com/s/question/0D54O00007Kfh7MSAR/what-is-the-format-used-to-represent-date-and-time-in-the-logstamp-field?language=en_US

In short the syncstamp/logstamp is a base 36 number that when divided by 50 gives you the number of seconds since midnight on 1/1/1990.

A few SQL functions have been posted in the past that can successfully navigate the math of creating/decrypting them.

Here's a set by, I think, Pat Connelly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GMSyncStampFromDate



(@datetime DATETIME)



RETURNS VARCHAR(7)



AS



BEGIN



declare @p1 bigint set @p1 = 36

declare @p2 bigint set @p2 = @p1 * @p1

declare @p3 bigint set @p3 = @p2 * @p1

declare @p4 bigint set @p4 = @p3 * @p1

declare @p5 bigint set @p5 = @p4 * @p1

declare @p6 bigint set @p6 = @p5 * @p1

declare @p7 bigint set @p7 = @p6 * @p1



declare @digits char(36)

set @digits = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'





declare @gmstamp varchar(7) set @gmstamp = ''



-- Get the time serial since the beginning of GoldMine time.

declare @s bigint

set @s=datediff(second,'1990-01-01T00:00:00.000',@datetime)*50.0

if (@s / @p7)> 0 return ''





-- Build the base 36 number string.

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p6),1) set @s=@s%@p6

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p5),1) set @s=@s%@p5

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p4),1) set @s=@s%@p4

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p3),1) set @s=@s%@p3

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p2),1) set @s=@s%@p2

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s / @p1),1) set @s=@s%@p1

select @gmstamp = @gmstamp + substring(@digits,1+(@s),1)



-- Remove leading zeros.

while (left(@gmstamp, 1) = '0' )

begin

 if (Len(@gmstamp) > 1) set @gmstamp = substring(@gmstamp, 2,len(@gmstamp))

end



return @gmstamp



-- test me

-- select dbo.f_GMSyncStampFromDate(current_timestamp)

END



 

create function syncstamper(@timestamp char(7))

returns datetime

as

begin



--This formula converts a Goldmine logstamp or syncstamp into a real datetime value. The returned value is

--the GMT time for the stamp, and NOT the regional or daylight saving adjusted time.





--Define all required variables

declare @ts1 char(1)

declare @ts2 char(1)

declare @ts3 char(1)

declare @ts4 char(1)

declare @ts5 char(1)

declare @ts6 char(1)

declare @ts7 char(1)

declare @date datetime





--Break timestamp into component characters

set @ts1 = substring(@timestamp,1,1)

set @ts2 = substring(@timestamp,2,1)

set @ts3 = substring(@timestamp,3,1)

set @ts4 = substring(@timestamp,4,1)

set @ts5 = substring(@timestamp,5,1)

set @ts6 = substring(@timestamp,6,1)

set @ts7 = substring(@timestamp,7,1)



numberVar D1N;

numberVar D2N;

numberVar D3N;

numberVar D4N;

numberVar D5N;

numberVar D6N;

numberVar D7N;

numberVar DF;



datetimeVar timestamp;

numberVar i:=9;





--Create the array of characters

stringVar array digits:= ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',



'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')



--Determine the character code for each character

For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D1=digits[i]

then D1N:=i-1);



 

For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D2=digits[i]

then D2N:=i-1);





For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D3=digits[i]

then D3N:=i-1);



 



For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D4=digits[i]

then D4N:=i-1);





For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D5=digits[i]

then D5N:=i-1);





For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D6=digits[i]

then D6N:=i-1);



 

For i:=1 to 36 do

(if D7=digits[i]

then D7N:=i-1);



 

//Multiply each digit by its factor and divide by 50 to get number of seconds

D1N:=D1N*2176782336/50;

D2N:=D2N*60466176/50;

D3N:=D3N*1679616/50;

D4N:=D4N*46656/50;

D5N:=D5N*1296/50;

D6N:=D6N*36/50;

D7N:=D7N*1/50;





//Add all the seconds together

DF:=D1N+D2N+D3N+D4N+D5N+D6N+D7N;





//Add the time onto the base time of 1st January 1990

timestamp:=DateAdd('s',DF,DateTime(1990,01,01,00,00,00));





//Display time

timestamp



return (@date)



end
```